# How to pay via Bitpay

Tags: bitpay

I'm trying to develop an app which integrates with the Bitpay API.
I managed to create an invoice which contains the URL in which to pay with Bitcoins:

[image]

But the problem is when I click on the Pay with Bitcoin button it redirects me to an address similar to this one:

```
bitcoin:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?amount=0.0012
```

Is this really how its supposed to work? How do I actually pay and complete the transaction? Can you walk me through the process of paying via Bitpay?
Please enlighten me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is expected behavior, it will be handled by applications that register the bitcoin URI, particularly this is prevalent in mobile clients.  Here is a couple links with more information on this topic:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=187597.0

http://electrum.org/bitcoin_URIs.html

Comment: does this all happen inside the browser? isn't there any need for special configuration or application in the server?

Comment: It is implemented in the browser on the client side.  The wallet application can/should register the URI (some do not and need to be manually configured) you may want to configure your app to display the address or perhaps a qr code on the screen for alternate implementations.